# how do i concat many column in MySQL, when its null its gonna skip, when its all null its gonna have "-" output

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how do i concat many column in MySQL, when its null its gonna skip, when its all null its gonna have "-" output

table1

| address | village | region | province | regency | postal_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | 1 |
| a | b | c | Null | e | 2 |
| Null | b | c | d | e | 3 |
| Null | Null | Null | Null | Null | Null |

Expected Condition :

| new_column |
| --- |
| a, b, c, ,d, e, 1 |
| a, b, c, e, 2 |
| b, c, d, e, 3 |
| - |

Answer (score 1):

A simple case statement will do the trick:

```
select case 
         when address is null 
          and village is null 
          and region is null 
          and province is null
          and regency is null 
          and postal_code is null then '-'
       else CONCAT_WS(',',address,village,region,province,regency,postal_code)
      end as new_column
from test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/2chZBzcS

[CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument

Instead of multiple and you could use COALESCEas proposed by [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) in the comments section :

```
select case 
         when COALESCE(address, village, region, province, regency, postal_code) is null 
            then '-'
            else CONCAT_WS(',',address,village,region,province,regency,postal_code)
        end as new_column
from test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/fDXtGvOe

Comment: You could also use `COALESCE(address, village, region, province, regency, postal_code)`. If the result is NULL, then all of those columns are NULL.

Comment: @BillKarwin it is much shorter with COALESCE  added an edit